# How to get token Iterator to combine digits

Tags: java, iterator, expression, token

I have this code that reads each token of an expression. output should be this. How do I get it to where the numbers will be together?

next token: [15]

next token: [*]

next token: [(]

next token: [26]
etc....

but instead i get this...

next token: [1]

next token: [5]

next token: [*]

next token: [(]

next token: [2]

next token: [6]

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TokenIter implements Iterator<String>{

// This class builds a Token Iterator, that produces 
// Strings containing numbers (sequences of digits) and 
// special characters: "(" ")" "+" "-"  "*" "/"

//input line to be tokenized
private String line;

// the next Token, null if no next Token
private String nextToken;

public TokenIter(String line){
    this.line = line;
}
static int counter = 0;

public void remove() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}


public static void main(String[] args){
    String line = "  15*(26+37) - 432/5*61 - (321-1234567)   ";
    System.out.println("line: [" + line + "]");
    TokenIter tokIt = new TokenIter(line);
    // print tokens in square brackets to check absence of white space
    while(tokIt.hasNext()){
        if (tokIt.next() != "no")
            System.out.println("next token: [" + tokIt.next() + "]");

        else
        {

        }
        counter++;

    }   
}
public boolean hasNext(){ 
    if (counter < line.length())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}

//char c;

public String next() {
    //String L = line.trim();
    String s = "";
    //  for (int index =0; index < L.length(); index++){
    if (!hasNext())
        return null;
    else{
        {
            char c = line.charAt(counter);
            if( c == ('/'))
            {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if( c == ('+'))
            {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if( c == ('*'))
            {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if( c == ('-'))
            {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if( c == ('('))
            {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            if( c == (')'))
            {
                counter = counter++;
                s = "" + c;
                return s;
            }
            else if (c == ' ')
            {
                counter = counter++;
                return "no";
            }

            else if (c == ('0'|'1'| '2' | '3'|'4'|'5'| '6'| '7' |'8' | '9'))
            {
                counter = counter++;
                return s;
            }
            else if (Character.isDigit(c)){
                if((c == '0') || (c == '1') ||(c == '2') ||(c == '3') ||(c == '4') ||(c == '5') ||(c == '6') ||(c == '7') ||(c == '8') || (c == '9'))
                    counter = counter++;
                s += "" + c;
                return s;
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}}
```

Comment: You need a `while` loop to accumulate adjacent digits. Hard to see the point of the final `else if` block *and* the previous one, which doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @EJP I tried doing a while loop, but im still getting the same results. what do I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to build an mathematical expression decomplier.  There are many ways to accomplish this.  One way is to use String tokenizer and set your delimiters:

public String nextToken(String delim)

However, using string tokenizer class is not accepted anymore.  The split method is the recommended method.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with some regex magic. The idea is you want to split the string but also keep the delimiters. This can be done with a look ahead or a look behind but the delimiter ends up attached to one side or the other. To fix that you need to use both. This will cause delimiters to be returned as separate tokens.

```
// Define the characters to split on: ' ', '+', '-', '*', '\', '(', ')'
final String splitOn = "\\+|-|\\*|/|\\(|\\)";
final String lookAheadGroup = "(?=" + splitOn + ")";
final String lookBehindGroup = "(?<=" + splitOn + ")";
final String regex = "(" + lookBehindGroup + "|" + lookAheadGroup + ")";
```

This regex can be used with String.split()

```
String line = "  15*(26+37) - 432/5*61 - (321-1234567)   ";
String[] tokens = line.split(regex);
for (String token : tokens) {
    System.out.printf("'%s'\n", token);
}
```

or with a Scanner

```
System.out.println("\n\nScanner");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
scanner.useDelimiter(regex);

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    System.out.printf("'%s'\n", scanner.next());
}
scanner.close();
```

**Example output**

Note that the tokens do don't have extra white space trimmed off so you will have to do that if your post processing is sensitive to it.

```
'15', '*', '(', '26', '+', '37', ')', ' ', '-', ' 432', '/', '5', '*', '61 ', '-', ' ', '(', '321', '-', '1234567', ')',
```